# Erro: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale (erro em função para posicionar "n" no gráfico)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou plotando alguns *boxplots* para comparar, ano a ano, as notas de estudantes periodizados e não periodizados. Estou utilizando a função abaixo para plotar esses gráficos. Dentro da função **stat_summary** estou utilizando a função `give.n` que retorna o tamanho de cada grupo, plotando esse "n" na coordenada y = 102 do gráfico.

```
# Função give.n para calcular o tamanho do grupo:
give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = 102, label = length(x)))
}

# boxplot ggplot2:
notas_dp <- ggplot(data = dados3,
               aes(x = dados3$PERIOD, y = dados3$NOTA_FINAL))
notas_dp + geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ dados3$ANO_DISCIPLINA) +
  labs(x = "\nPeriodização\n",
       y = "\nNotas finais\n",
       title = "Notas finais quanto à periodização dos estudantes aprovados",
       subtitle = "P = periodizado; NP = Não periodizado") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Notas finais", breaks = seq(0, 100, 10)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=70), colour="blue", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=50), colour="red", linetype = "solid") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median)
```

- Meu gráfico está saindo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei alterar a função `give.n` para que ela retorne no gŕafico a informação **`n = 50`**, por exemplo, e não somente o número 50.

```
# Alteração da função give.n:
give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = 102, label = paste("n = ", length(x))))
}
```

No entanto, quando rodo meu gráfico ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Erro: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
> ```

Não estou conseguindo posicionar a função `paste()` da base do R em lugar nenhum para concatenar o **`"n = "`** junto do resultado da função `give.n`.

Abaixo, segue o output de `dput(head(dados3, 10))` (retirei os dados da coluna GRR pois são dados não públicos, mas são strings de 11 caracteres).

```
structure(list(
    GRR = structure(c(23L, 49L, 54L, 56L, 61L, 47L, 
107L, 93L, 60L, 95L), .Label = c("GRR2015****", ..., "GRR2018****"), class = "factor"), 
    ANO_GRR = structure(c(7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L), .Label = c("2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
    "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018"), class = "factor"), 
    NOTA_FINAL = c(86, 76, 88, 88, 90, 88, 88, 74, 78, 75), SITU_FINAL = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Aprovado", 
    "Cancelado", "Reprovado por Frequência", "Reprovado por nota", 
    "Trancamento Total"), class = "factor"), 
    ANO_DISCIPLINA = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2015", "2016", 
    "2017", "2018"), class = "factor"), 
    PERIOD = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Jubilados", 
    "P", "NP"), class = "factor"), 
    PROF = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("XXXXX", "XXXXX", 
    "XXXXX"), class = "factor"), 
    ANO_DESPERIOD = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
   .Names = c("GRR", "ANO_GRR", "NOTA_FINAL", 
"SITU_FINAL", "ANO_DISCIPLINA", "PERIOD", "PROF", "ANO_DESPERIOD"
), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), 
    class = "data.frame")
```

Agradeço se alguém puder ajudar. Obrigada!

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados3)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados3, 20))`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Edição feita. A base não é muito grande, mas para melhorar a visualização especifiquei 10 linhas no comando `head()`. Alguns dados coloquei com *** ou XXX porque são informações não públicas.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se é possível fazer isso com stat_summary. Uma opção é usar `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(data = dados3,
       aes(x = PERIOD, y = NOTA_FINAL)) +
geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ ANO_DISCIPLINA) +
  labs(x = "\nPeriodização\n",
       y = "\nNotas finais\n",
       title = "Notas finais quanto à periodização dos estudantes aprovados",
       subtitle = "P = periodizado; NP = Não periodizado") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Notas finais", breaks = seq(0, 100, 10)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=70), colour="blue", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=50), colour="red", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_text(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = dados3 %>% group_by(PERIOD) %>% count(), 
             aes(label = paste0("n = ", n), x = PERIOD, y = 102))
```